# Fastest one-to-one mapping of binary 1d Numpy array to integer

Tags: python, performance, numpy, mapping, cython

What's the fastest way of converting a 1d Numpy array containing only `0`s and `1`s to a *unique* integer?

The best I came up with so far is to use Cython and see the array as a mirrored binary number*.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def _map_binary(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] x):

    cdef int tot = 0
    cdef int i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        if x[i]:
            tot += 2**i
    return tot
```

As this is still the bottleneck of my algorithm, I am wondering if there's a smarter and faster way to do it.

* Obviously this mapping is one-to-one only for arrays with the same length (as appending zeros to the array doesn't change the resulting integer), but this is fine for my purposes.

Comment: Not sure of it's speed but you could try `int("".join([str(c) for c in x]),2)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069825/convert-binary-01-numpy-to-integer-or-binary-string

Comment: You don't need to do `** 2` on each iteration, you could keep a variable and multiply it by 2 on each iteration, I don't know if it would make a noticeable difference though.

Comment: I'd guess that `1<<i` (bitshift) might be a little faster than `2**i`. (You could also combine this with what @FranciscoCouzo suggests)

Comment: Second suggestion would be to specify the array as contiguous (`mode=c`), provided that it is, of course.

Comment: Base on @AriGold's link, the fastest one on NumPy seems to be  `np.dot(x,1 << np.arange(x.size))`.

Comment: @NickA, everything having to do with strings is quite slow, same goes for Numpy methods, still in the microseconds range @Divakar. Regarding @DavidW 's and @FranciscoCouzo 's suggestions, I suppose there might be marginal improvements but I think I need a more precise timing approach then the easy `%timeit` to really see if they are there. Suggestions for more accurate timing are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Collating some of the ideas from the comments and some of my own

A few pure Python (+numpy) options:

```
import numpy as np

def _map_binary_str_and_back(x):
    # from comment by @NickA
    return int("".join([str(c) for c in x]),2)

def _map_binary_np_dot(x):
    # from question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069825/convert-binary-01-numpy-to-integer-or-binary-string
    return np.dot(x,1 << np.arange(x.size))

def _map_binary_np_pack(x):
    # uses built in numpy function packbits, but unfortunately needs a bit of manipulation
    # afterwards
    x = np.packbits(x) # as np.int8
    x.resize((8,),refcheck=False)
    return x.view(dtype=np.int64)
```

Some Cython options (note that I've changed the output to a 64-bit integer so that it works with arrays up to 64 elements long):

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

def _map_binary_original(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] x):

    cdef np.uint64_t tot = 0
    cdef np.uint64_t i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        if x[i]:
            tot += 2**i
    return tot

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def _map_binary_contig(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] x):

    cdef np.uint64_t tot = 0
    cdef np.uint64_t i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        if x[i]:
            tot += 2**i
    return tot

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
def _map_binary_shift(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] x):

    cdef np.uint64_t tot = 0
    cdef np.uint64_t i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        if x[i]:
            tot += 1<<i
    return tot

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
def _map_binary_times2(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] x):
    # @FranciscoCouzo

    cdef np.uint64_t tot = 0
    cdef np.uint64_t i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        tot *= 2
        if x[i]:            
            tot +=1 
    return tot

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
def _map_binary_times2_as_shift(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] x):

    cdef np.uint64_t tot = 0
    cdef np.uint64_t i
    cdef int n = x.shape[0]

    for i in xrange(n):
        tot *= 2
        if x[i]:            
            tot +=1 
    return tot
```

And (for reference) some timing code

```
from map_binary import (_map_binary_original,_map_binary_contig,
                        _map_binary_shift,_map_binary_times2,
                        _map_binary_times2_as_shift)

test_array = np.random.randint(2,size=(60,)).astype(dtype=np.int64)

def time_function(name):
    from timeit import timeit

    num = 10000
    timed = timeit("f(x)","from __main__ import {} as f, test_array as x".format(name),number=num)/num
    print(name, timed)

for n in list(globals().keys()):
    if n.startswith('_map_binary'):
        time_function(n)
```

The results (slightly reformatted for clarity):

```
_map_binary_str_and_back    9.774386967484043e-05
_map_binary_np_dot          7.402434574531678e-06
_map_binary_np_pack         1.5813756692768855e-06
_map_binary_original        7.462656716457738e-07
_map_binary_contig          7.208434833198e-07
_map_binary_shift           5.84043665719558e-07
_map_binary_times2          6.467991376011505e-07
_map_binary_times2_as_shift 6.412435894529889e-07
```

In summary:

- Of the "no Cython" versions using `np.packbits` is the quickest option by some margin (but obviously worse than the Cython versions). However the no-Cython versions need further work to ensure they give the same answer (I think dot is suffering from an integer overflow. `packbits` flips the endianness, so gives a valid but different answer)
- Specifying the contiguous-ness of the array makes things marginally quicker.
- Shift seems the fastest, followed by multiplying followed by power (shift is only the fastest if you use unsigned integers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your solution is the best way at an algorithmic perspective but for the sake of writing more optimized Cython codes I'd suggest following changes:

1. Using memory-view arrays in Cython
2. Using non-pythonic codes when you are using Cython, so that Cython can generate smaller C codes from your python code. So instead of using `shape` and indexing since you have a 1D array you can use `size()` and instead of using `xrange` and indexing just loop over the array and increase the variable `i` in each iteration (or at least just use `range()`), that's because `xrange` is a generator and requires more work to be converted to C.
3. Using C libraries like `pow`
4. Predefine the type your functions

---

```
form ibc.math cimport pow

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef int _map_binary(np.int32_t[:] x):
    cdef int tot = 0
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef int n = x.size
    cdef int item
    for item in x:
        if item:
            tot = tot + pow(2, i)
        i = i + 1
    return tot
```

Comment: Cython actually converts `xrange` and `range` to a simple C loop, so they actually are the best way of doing things. I think (but could be wrong) that `for item in x` will the use the Python iterator interface and be comparatively slow.

Comment: @DavidW Agreed, but I'm not sure too. The only thing that I'm sure is that `xragnge` is slower than the rest.

Comment: @Kasramvd, thank you for your answer. I don't think using `cdef` is an option for me as this function needs to be available to Python code, at least for now. Secondly, `pow(2,i)` appears to return a double, which means you can't add it to `tot`. Overall, it's much slower (worse than my pure Python version). You are right though that I can get a marginal speedup by turning `xrange` into `range`.

Comment: @PietroMarchesi Regarding `cdef` you should call this function in your cython code with another python function (which has been defined by `def`). And regarding `pow()` you're right it returns double, and in that case, you can return a double too, or if you don't want to do this using simple python power would be good too as it's not a big deal here.

Comment: But after all, I recommend you to change your algorithm instead of the implementation, then if you needed more performance you can turn that to a Cython code.