# how to convert a dataframe containing 1's and 0's and add a new column to the same dataframe that represents the hex value of entire row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, boolean, numpy-ndarray

[image]

I have a dataframe of 51 rows and 464 columns , the columns contain 1's and 0's. I want to have a encoded value of the hex as you see in the attached picture.

I was trying to use numpy to make the hex conversion but it would fail

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(51, 464)))
#converting into numpy for easier shifting
a = df.values
b = a.dot(2**np.arange(a.size)[::-1])
```

I want to have every 4 columns grouped to produce the hexadecimal value and then if there are odd columns for ex: 463 instead of 464 then the trailing hexadecimal will be padded with zero or zeroes based on how many ever needed to make the full hexadecimal value

This code only works for 64 bits length and then fails.
I was following this example
[binary0|1 to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069825/convert-binary-01-numpy-to-integer-or-binary-string)

any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: How about appending to a string and then converting that to a hex?

Comment: could you show me with an example?

Comment: Please [edit] your code into your question. This allows the people volunteering their time to quickly repurpose your code for their suggestions instead of starting from scratch. If you correctly converted each row to a list, it should be fairly easy to [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them all into a single string and go from there

Comment: I have edited the question to the current method i was trying, please let me know

Comment: P.s. `randint` is exclusive, so it should be `(0, 2, ...)`

Comment: aah yes that's a typo, cleaned it up

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFE (12 Fs and an E, 4x12=48+3=51)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```py
df.apply(lambda row: hex(int(''.join(map(str, row)), base=2)), axis=1)
```

1. Convert to string every number in a row
2. Join them to create one big number in string
3. Convert it to integer with base 2 (since a row is in binary format)
4. Convert it to hex

**Edit:** To convert every 4 piece with the same manner:

```py
def hexize(row):
    hexes = '0x'
    
    row = ''.join(map(str, row))

    for i in range(0, len(row), 4):
        value = row[i:i+4]
        value = value.ljust(4, '0')  # right fill with 0
        value = hex(int(value, base=2))
        
        hexes += value[2:]
        
    return hexes

df.apply(hexize, axis=1)
hexize('011101100')  # returns '0x760'
```

Comment: Sorry the numbers are actually in binary, not decimal. I'm going to update my answer or remove it if I fail.

Comment: I have added `base=2` to int conversion

Comment: that works, but when i have odd columns the MSB is getting ignored, For ex: if  i have 9 columns with value 0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0. I would like it to be 0x760 instead i end up with 0xec

Comment: Is MSB the column 1 or 464?

Comment: not particularly, i want every 4 columns to be become hexadecimal value and if odd amount of columns then the last column will be padded with enough zeroes to make it a hexadecimal value .
i guess in a way you can say column1 is MSB

Comment: Ahh, I think that should've been cleared in the question :)

Comment: yup, sorry updated the question to have that detail

Comment: @NandeepDevendra If column 1 is MSB, shouldn't the 2nd row be 0x8 not 0x1?  The conversion isn't clear from the examples.

Comment: I have updated my answer. @MarkTolonen you're actually right.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  you  are right it should be 0x8

Answer (score 1):

Given input data:

```
ECID,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22,T23,T24,T25,T26,T27,T28,T29,T30,T31,T32,T33,T34,T35,T36,T37,T38,T39,T40,T41,T42,T43,T44,T45,T46,T47,T48,T49,T50,T51
ABC123,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
XYZ345,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
DEF789,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
434thECID,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

This adds an "Encoded" column similar to what was asked.  The first row example in the original question seems to have the wrong number of Fs:

```py
import pandas as pd

def encode(row):
    s = ''.join(str(x) for x in row[1:])  # Create binary string
    s += '0' * (4 - len(row[1:]) % 4)     # Make length a multiple of 4 by adding zeros
    i = int(s,2)                          # convert to integer base 2
    h = hex(i).rstrip('0')                # strip trailing zeros
    return h if h != '0x' else '0x0'      # Handle special case of '0x0' stripping to '0x'
    
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['Encoded'] = df.apply(encode,axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        ECID  T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  ...  T47  T48  T49  T50  T51          Encoded
0     ABC123   1   1   1   1   1  ...    1    1    1    1    1  0xffffffffffffe
1     XYZ345   1   0   0   0   0  ...    0    0    0    0    0              0x8
2     DEF789   1   0   1   0   1  ...    0    0    0    0    0             0xaa
3  434thECID   0   0   0   0   0  ...    0    0    0    0    0              0x0

[4 rows x 53 columns]
```